# Python Django error NoReverseMatch Exception Value: Reverse for 'updatecontact' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a function that update data in the DB. Here is my url:

**url.py**

```
url(r'updatecontact/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.updatecontact,name="updatecontact"),
```

**template.html**

```
<td><a href="/updatecontact/{{a.id}}/">Update</a></td>
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'updatecontact' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['updatecontact/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: try url below (add specific id instead of `{{ a.id }}` with existing object.). `<td><a href="/updatecontact/1/">Update</a></td>`. What happen?

Comment: If error occured, I think your view has problem. then please upload your views.updatecontact

Answer (score 0):

change your url to

```
url(r'^updatecontact/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.updatecontact,name="updatecontact"),
```

and in your template you can use

```
{% url 'updatecontact' a.pk %}
```

instead of typing whole url

Comment: is object `a` have an `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding slash `/` in your url.
like:

```
url(r'/updatecontact/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.updatecontact,name="updatecontact"),
```

Comment: all good it was my fault. the error was taiga from a typepo from the template.

Comment: It’s usually a mistake to add a leading slash like this, unless there is an `include()` without a trailing slash.